# How to reuse code

Tags: inheritance

I have three classes.

Monster derives from Animation. Animation derives from Collider. This is, monster is an animated collider.

However, I'd like to have animated objects that are not colliders.

Maybe it's a newbie question, but how?

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the best examples why use [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). When you learned coding OOP, you were very often advised to derive... and derive, and derive. This is usually not (that) bad for applications but you will run into serious problems in games very soon. Exactly whose what you posted. 
[Entity component system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) design is frequently advised solution for games.